# Chrome Extension Upload: zip file unable to upload 'manifest.json:26:1: unknown syntax error'

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

When I tried to upload the zip file, it shows 'manifest.json:26:1: unknown syntax error'

My json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Real French Toast",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "hahaha",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "RealFrenchToast.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"

  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried installing a dummy extension with this manifest successfully. BTW the file has only 25 lines. Apparently your manifest.json has a bad character on the last line. You may investigate it in a hex viewer/editor.

Fix: copypaste the contents into a new file and save it as `manifest.json` overwriting the old file.